# Can't install ghc on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, software-center

I'm just trying to install `ghc` on my computer. I typed

```
sudo apt-get install ghc
```

into the terminal. I then was asked did I want to install, I said yes. Then I was asked did I want to install unverified files. I said yes. Then I got a bunch of error 404's and finally an error:

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried installing it via the Software Center and I got a pop up saying:

> This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources.

I clicked OK and it just stopped installing.

Can anyone help me just simply install `ghc`?

After running `sudo apt-get update` I get this:

[image: sudo apt-get update output]

When I type `sudo apt-get install ghc` I get this:

[image: sudo apt-get install ghc output]

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update`, and please post a representative section of the error messages as well (a couple of the 404s, if you will).

Comment: You can copy-paste text errors, instead of posting screenshots. That said, there's your problem. You're on 12.10, not 12.04. 12.10 is unsupported.

Comment: does this mean I have to reinstall ubuntu to a newer version?

Comment: No, you *can* upgrade, but you will have to do so thrice, from 12.10 to 13.04, from 13.04 to 13.10 and 13.10 to 14.04 to reach a supported release. It would be simpler to reinstall.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing the packages on this list: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/haskell-platform

```
sudo apt-get install ghc alex cabal-install happy libghc-cgi-dev libghc-fgl-dev libghc-glut-dev libghc-haskell-src-dev libghc-html-dev libghc-http-dev libghc-hunit-dev libghc-mtl-dev libghc-network-dev libghc-opengl-dev libghc-parallel-dev libghc-parsec3-dev  libghc-quickcheck2-dev libghc-regex-base-dev libghc-regex-compat-dev  libghc-regex-posix-dev libghc-stm-dev libghc-syb-dev  libghc-text-dev  libghc-transformers-dev  libghc-xhtml-dev libghc-zlib-dev
```

Hope this helps!